# Get a regular text line formatted as a section heading

Tags: formatting, koma-script, section-titles

Imagine that I need to place inside the text an example of how a section heading looks like. I.e. I need to format a line of text exactly the way a section heading is formatted, but without starting a new section.

The best I could do is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\KOMAoptions{headings = big}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Real section heading}

Here is how section  heading looks like:

\usekomafont{section}
\sectionlinesformat{section}{0pt}{}{Simulated section heading}

\end{document}
```

Which produce this:

[image]

and is not what I want. It misses the font settings, beforeskip, and afterskip.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use just `\addsec*{...}`?

Comment: `\addsec*` actually starts a new section. It will clear the running head and reset counters.

Comment: What precisely do you mean by "actually starting a new section"?

Comment: Ok, since version 3.31 `\section*` (and `\addsec*`) resets counters, eg. the subsection counter.

Comment: `\addsec*` also clears running heads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `\usekomafont{disposition}`. The space before and after headings are not inserted by `\sectionlinesformat`. You would have to insert them manually.

But you could define a new heading command with the same settings as section:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, paper = B5]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\KOMAoptions{headings = big}
\addtokomafont{section}{\color{red}}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[
  style=section,
  level=\sectionnumdepth,
  tocstyle=gobble,% there will be no ToC entry
  beforeskip=\scr@section@beforeskip,
  afterskip=\scr@section@afterskip,
  font=\usekomafont{section},
  ]{mysection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text

\section*{Real section heading}
Here is how section heading looks like:
\mysection*{Simulated section heading}
More text

\end{document}
```

`\mysection` or `\mysection*` will not reset counters and not change or clear running heads.

Comment: This is clever. Thanks!